# How to make a set of views invisible in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a set of views (*that include several textviews and buttons - all in **different parent layouts**, but in the same activity*) invisible if a particular condition is evaluated to false.

The conventional way to do that would be:

```
findViewById(R.id.myview).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

My question is, will I have to do this for all the views one by one that I want to be invisible, And then toggle them back when I want them visible?
Or, is there a way to avoid the code-repetition?

Comment: just put all your views in parent layout...ans set its visibility...this will adjust visibility of all views inside it...

Comment: If somehow they can be arranged in single layout then only you can toggle visible/invisible in one go

Comment: yeah, but most of them fall in different parent layouts - whose other children must remain visible.

Comment: @Mohit it is not necessary if OP wants to hide all views from parent layouts

Comment: if so then you have to do it individually

Comment: so, there is no concept of "grouping" the views and controlling the whole group dynamically? Okay, doing individual is the last option.

Comment: when they are in different parents then you can't

Comment: put them into a (weak)hashmap at creation time and iterate over that map for toggling them visible/invisible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `View`s are in different parents , you can't do it directly, but you can implement a method to change the visibility of a bunch of `View`s if you want to keep your code clean:

```
List<View> relatedViews = new ArrayList<>();

// ...

relatedViews.add(view1);
relatedViews.add(view2);
relatedViews.add(view3);

// ...

changeVisibility(relatedViews, View.INVISIBLE);

// ...

private void changeVisibility(List<View> views, int visibility) {
    for (View view : views) {
        view.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
}
```

As a side note, you may want to change the visibility to `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE` so it doesn't take any space in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this. It's not the most elegant solution but works.

The idea is give to each view that you want to hide a same content description, because in the same layout you can not use same id for multiple view. With the same content description you can find all views in your layout and hide them.
That's an example considering the first layout as Linear. You can change obviously ;)

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

            LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

            int childcount = rootLayout.getChildCount();
            for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
                View v = rootLayout.getChildAt(i);
                if(v.getContentDescription() != null && v.getContentDescription().equals("invisibleView")){
                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   //I suggest you to use GONE instead of INVISIBLE to remove the space of the view
                }
            }

        }
}
```

in your xml give to the object that you want to hide this property

```
android:contentDescription="invisibleView"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `varargs` method for show or hide multiple views.

for example if you have views like view1, view2.....etc

then just call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE,view1,view2)`

```
public static void setVisibility(int visibility, View... views){
    for (View view : views){
       view.setVisibility(visibility);
    }
}
```